# I can't delete old kernel, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: kernel, cleanup

I have tried Ubuntu Tweak, Synaptic and some command line stuff I found online, but nothing seems to work.

This is the output of `dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii`

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                               3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                         3.13.0.24.29                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

What are my options? I only need to free 3 MB for a the kernel update.

Thanks in advance!

When I run this, I get that output:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Generando archivo de configuración grub...
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-19-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-19-generic
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-17-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-17-generic
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-16-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-16-generic
Se encontró una imagen linux: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic
Se encontró una imagen initrd: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Encontrado en Windows 7 (loader) en /dev/sda1
Encontrado en Windows 7 (loader) en /dev/sda8
hecho
```

But when I try to delete one of those entries, I get this:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic»
```

Basically, it says it doesn't find the package or image I'm trying to delete.

```
$ dpkg -l linux-image* 
Deseado=Desconocido/Instalar/Eliminar/Purgar/Retener
| Estado=No/Instalado/Config-files/Desempaquetado/Medio-conf/Medio-inst/espera-disparo/pendiente-disparo
|/ Err?=(ninguno)/Requiere-reinst (Estado,Err: mayúsc.=malo)
||/ Nombre                                             Versión                        Arquitectura                   Descripción
+++-==================================================-==============================-==============================-==========================================================================================================
un  linux-image                                        <ninguna>                      <ninguna>                      (no hay ninguna descripción disponible)
un  linux-image-3.0                                    <ninguna>                      <ninguna>                      (no hay ninguna descripción disponible)
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                      3.13.0-24.47                   amd64                          Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                3.13.0-24.47                   amd64                          Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic
```

PS: is it possible to delete the current kernel or the extras (linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic) and, at the same time, install the newest kernel, all of this using Synaptic?

Comment: Maybe `sudo apt-get autoclean` or `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: First install new kernel, _then_ remove old. And I suggest you to test new before removing old. Things may occur. If you have room only for one kernel, you did it wrong and have to resize your `/boot` partition.

Comment: @skyroma thanks, already tried that and emptying the Bin, doens't work

Comment: @Danatela I always could upgrade my kernel, and Ubuntu Tweak would do the trick by deleting old kernels. Now it just seem to have ran out of space and I don't know what to delete to fix this.

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg -l linux-image*`

Comment: OK, just edited the question with that output @bain

Comment: Looks like you have a bunch of files that don't belong to any package. Assuming you are currently running 3.13.0, you can just do `rm /boot/*-3.0.0-12-generic`

Comment: That did the job, @bain! You rule! How can I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have a bunch of files that don't belong to any package. Assuming you are currently running 3.13.0, you can just do `rm /boot/*-3.0.0-12-generic`

Answer (score 9):

Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and chek the current kernel version:

```
uname -r
```

***DO NOT REMOVE THIS KERNEL!***

Copy and paste below command and hit run to check list of installed Kernels on your system:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Find out the kernels you want to remove, and run below command to accomplish it: **Change x.x.x.x to the kernel version**

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the following bash script (run as sudo).
it purges/removes all 'old' kernels.

```
#/bin/bash 
ls /boot/ | grep vmlinuz | sed 's@vmlinuz-@linux-image-@g' | grep -v `uname -r` > /tmp/kernelList 
for I in `cat /tmp/kernelList`
do 
  #sudo aptitude remove $I 
  sudo apt-get purge --assume-yes $I
  #echo $I
done
rm -f /tmp/kernelList 
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your dpkg listing does not indicate that the packages for the old kernels exist, feel free to just delete the old unwanted files from /boot.   Then take a look at /lib/modules, and remove the old module directories there too.  Certainly the 3.0.0-12, 16, and 17 may be delete this way, leaving you with enough room for the new kernel.